# Play 2 framework importing play 2modules

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I have created a play framework with heroku and have imported it to my local eclipse. How do i import the following play2 module into my project.

https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate

What do I add to the dependencies.yml?

Comment: There is no `dependencies.yml` in Play2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project you link to has samples in it. Just read them. 
It happens in the [Build.scala](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/samples/java/play-authenticate-simple-oauth/project/Build.scala) file.